# What is the most stylistically correct way to declare these variables?

Tags: java, initialization

I am somewhat new to computer science and I have written a project that uses a lot of variables.  I have all the code in the main method and at the beginning of the main method, I have most of my variables declared.  I think this is pretty ugly.  I don't want to change around my whole code and mess with the scope.  Is there a way to declare these same variables and have it look more efficient/professional?

```
int numPlain;
int numPepperoni;
int pizzasOrdered = 0;
int slicesOrdered = 0;
int charmsOrdered = 0;
int totalSlices = 0;
int totalCharms = 0;
int totalPlain = 0;
int totalPepperoni = 0;
double plainCost = 0.0;
double pepperoniCost = 0.0;
double sliceCost = 0.0;
double pieCost = 0.0;
double charmCost = 0.0;
boolean flag = true;
double totalCost = 0.00;
double paymentAmt = 0.0;
int numPies = 0;
```

Comment: start looking at classes i.e seperate class for pizza, toppings, etc and this way you start learning about abstraction and class interaction

Comment: This is pretty much perfect and not much you could change. Like others have said, you could separate them in different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* try to inline some of your variable declarations/initializations like this:

```
int numPlain, numPepperoni;
int pizzasOrdered = 0, slicesOrdered = 0, charmsOrdered = 0;
int totalSlices = 0, totalCharms = 0, totalPlain = 0, totalPepperoni = 0;
double plainCost = 0.0, pepperoniCost = 0.0, sliceCost = 0.0, pieCost = 0.0, charmCost = 0.0;
boolean flag = true;
double totalCost = 0.00;
double paymentAmt = 0.0;
int numPies = 0;
```

This would make the code appear a bit less verbose and also groups together variables which are related to each other.

Comment: I still think that he has too many fields. A good code checking tool would complain about this. He probably needs separate classes :)

Answer (score 0):

My old university professor always styled like this:

```
int     numPlain;
int     numPepperoni;
int     pizzasOrdered   = 0;
int     slicesOrdered   = 0;
int     charmsOrdered   = 0;
int     totalSlices     = 0;
int     totalCharms     = 0;
int     totalPlain      = 0;
int     totalPepperoni  = 0;

double  plainCost       = 0.0;
double  pepperoniCost   = 0.0;
double  sliceCost       = 0.0;
double  pieCost         = 0.0;
double  charmCost       = 0.0;

boolean flag            = true;

double  totalCost       = 0.00;
double  paymentAmt      = 0.0;

int     numPies         = 0;
```

It's all preference really though. The main key is just readability. As your progress, you wont have as many primitive variables in a single function as well.

**Edit:** Also notice, you can either group your variables together by type, or by relatedness (grouping variables together by their function)